# Logarithm function in sqlite query?

Tags: python, sqlite

I really need to perform an `update` on over 400,000 rows using the logarithm function. Unfortunately, the SQL logarithm function does not seem to exist in sqlite. Is there any way I can derive the logarithm function or import the `LOG` function?

The only other way I know how to do this is I believe order O(n^2) through python. This approach will take too long (I tried, it took about and 1.5 hours to go through 6% on my slow computer).

EDIT:

I also found out why it took so long. The primary key in the database was not marked as a primary key. So the code that I was using followed:

```
for row in database:
    ...calculations for the row...
    ...sql update for the specific row which follows:...
    for search_row in database:
        if search_row[id] = row[id]:
            ...update values here...
```

Incredibly inefficient... O(n^2)

Comment: If it's taking 1.5 hours to read 24k values from your db, calculate their log in Python, and write them back again, then something weird is happening...

Comment: Doing it all within a transaction may help. (Also, there is an API for defining functions in sqlite, it exists for C and for TCL, not sure about python).

Comment: And there are libraries which use the function API to provide additional functions such as Log(): http://search.cpan.org/~kjetil/SQLite-More-0.10/lib/SQLite/More.pm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in logarithm function; you have to define your own function.

If you're using Python, this is possible with both the [pysqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function) and [APSW](http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/connection.html#apsw.Connection.createscalarfunction) modules.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. I added `math.log` as the function `log` in the sqlite3 database with two arguments (to accomplish log256). The query took but a couple of seconds. Now the implementation that I had before sounds silly.

Comment: The links are dead but you can simply use `connection.create_function('log', 1, math.log10)`

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that math functions (including logarithm) are implemented in Sqlite but *disabled* in standard Sqlite compilation on Ubuntu. In order to enable them you should download Sqlite sources [from here](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?ci=tip) ("Obtaining the code") and compile according to the instructions ("Compiling"). The necessary option **-DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS** will be enabled by default. After compilation you will get the `sqlite3` executable in the build directory, this should be run as a local file:

```
$ ./sqlite3 <database-file>
```

BEFORE the compilation I recommend to install `readline` so that history browsing (the arrows) and auto-completion work correctly in the Sqlite command line.

```
sudo apt install libreadline-dev
```

Comment: Note that at the time of writing, this answer is correct for the latest trunk check-in only (3.35.0), not for the latest release (3.34.0). Not sure if this is a version thing, or if this is always the case.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think it will be `O(n^2)`? If anything, it should be linear: `O(n)`.

Just about the only reason why it is so slow if you use auto-commit mode - this would cause SQLite to flush buffers to disk on every single UPDATE.

If you start transaction, then use SELECT / UPDATE loop, and finally commit, your update should be very fast (provided that your logarithm function is not very slow).

Answer (score 1):

Those that only need it for natural sorting with a low precition (rounded after one decimal digit of the fraction, and only accurate up to 4 decimal places) but with good performance may use:

`( (length(count(*) * 1000 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 1258 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 1584 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 1995 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 2511 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 3162 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 3981 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 5011 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 6309 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 7943 / 1000)) / 10.0 - 1.0 )`

I needed it in a join where I was interested in the log of the number of entries in the joined n:m table, therefore i used 'count(*)' of which i calculated the logarithm.

`... ( ( ( ( (0.0 + length(count(*) * 1000 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 1258 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 1584 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 1995 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 2511 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 3162 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 3981 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 5011 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 6309 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 7943 / 1000)) / 10.0 - 1.0 ) * 10 +1 ) + ( IFNULL(stat.sum * 1.0 / (1848) , 0.9999999) ) ) / ( IFNULL(stat.count,1) +  ( ( (0.0 + length(count(*) * 1000 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 1258 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 1584 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 1995 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 2511 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 3162 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 3981 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 5011 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 6309 / 1000) + length(count(*) * 7943 / 1000)) / 10.0 - 1.0 ) *10 +1 ) ) ) as rating, stat.expl as expl from ...`

Instead of 'count(*)' any other integer variable may be used, just make sure it is an integer, or cast it to an integer. The length of a float obviously wouldn't do you any good.

This is a dirty trick, that uses the fact that the length of the string of a decimal represantation of an int is defined by a logarithm, and extracts it. But compared to a logorithm-implematation calculating all digits of a float, the int to string and counting the length seems to be rather efficient excepting the drawback of only one decimal place of precition. Best I could do with portable sqlite syntax.

P.S.: If anybody has any ideas on how to improve the precition, the performance or have a variable logarythm-base (instead of it beening fixed to be rounded down to the first decimal digit of a base of 10) please comment.

P.P.S: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9aadc/2/0

Answer (score 0):

Use `log10(number)` function.

For **anti log**, use `power(10, number)` function.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question nor is it correct Python code to do the calculation the OP is inquiring about. Please review the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to answer questions.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure why my answer is not useful. Searching for "logarithm function in sqlite query" got me to this page. This should benefit those who needs logarithm function in sqlite queries and comes to this page. Besides, using this sql function is another approach.

Comment: There is not a logarithmic function in SQLite therefore this answer will not work for what the OP needs it to do.

Comment: Maybe SQLite didn't have logarithmic function in the past. But I've tried "select log10(100)" and it gives the query result of 2, and "select power(10, 2)" will give the result of 100.

Comment: As of the [docs for the most recent release](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_corefunc.html) `logarithm` and `log10` are not base functions in SQLite3. Maybe the distribution you are using has this functionality built in but it is not in the base therefore your answer would need further detail to be a good answer. If you have other proof than please present it and I will change my downvote and comments.