# result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : Result too large

Tags: r, linear-regression, sqldf

```
t1_DA <- sqldf("select decile, 
               count(decile) as count, avg(pred_spent) as avg_pred_spent,   
               avg(exp(total_spent)) as avg_total_spent,
               avg(log(pred_spent)) as ln_avg_pred_spent,   
               avg(total_spent) as ln_avg_total_spent
               from t1
               group by decile
               order by decile desc")
```

I am doing linear regression on a file and when I run this part of the code I am getting following error

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : Result too large

Is there any way to overcome this error?

Comment: How big is `t1`?

Comment: 3500 observations and 112 variables

Comment: By default, sqldf is based on SQLite's SQL dialect. Check if it supports functions like `exp` and `log`.

Comment: That is certainly not large. Inline with @Parfait's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14552021/3358272. Neither of `exp` and `log` are listed on https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html.

Comment: Indeed it is not available for sqldf, the code works fine when i run it without exp and log. I will use that instead. Thanks for your help guys.@r2evans @Parfait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, by default `sqldf` uses the SQLite dialect which does not support extensive mathematical and statistical functions like `exp` and `log`. Admittedly, a better raised message can help users debug rather than *Result too large* (maybe a [git issue](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues) for author, @ggrothendieck?).

However, in order to integrate these outputs into your aggregate query, consider creating those columns *before* running in sqldf. Use either `transform` or `within` for easy new column assignment without constant reference to data frame using the `$` assignment approach.

```
t1 <- transform(t1, exp_total_spent = exp(total_spent),
                    log_pred_spent = log10(log_pred_spent)
                )
# ALTERNATIVE
t1 <- within(t1, {exp_total_spent <- exp(total_spent)
                  log_pred_spent <- log10(log_pred_spent)
             })

t1_DA <- sqldf("select decile, 
                       count(decile) as count, 
                       avg(pred_spent) as avg_pred_spent,   
                       avg(exp_total_spent) as avg_total_spent,
                       avg(log_pred_spent) as ln_avg_pred_spent,   
                       avg(total_spent) as ln_avg_total_spent
                from t1
                group by decile
                order by decile desc")
```

Comment: I will try this. Much appreciated.Thanks a lot! @Parfait